# How to build data.frame from text contained in one single column?

Tags: r, dataframe, testing

The issue is a single row of data that needs to be formatted into a R data.frame with appropriate columns to store the row data into column data. The original data is format is a text file with 2 rows of headers, and N rows of data. The data is in a single column. It needs to be formatted into separate columns.
Basically, how to split text from each single column to columns into a new data.frame?

INPUT EXAMPLE:

The input contains, for example, two rows which consists of a combined 1) header names, 2) sub-header names, and then N number of rows that contain one single column with all the data, e.g., RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990103,00:00....

OUTPUT EXPECTATION

A new R data.frame which would have column headers (sub-header) and columns that would be parsed from the single column data rows. For example: one single column data row looks like this:
RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990103. But this single column data would need to be formatted into separate data columns.

OUTPUT EXPECTED

```
  RD Action.Code State.Code County.Code Site.ID Parameter POC Sample.Duration   Unit
1 RC Action Code State Code County Code Site ID Parameter POC            Unit Method
2 RD           I         01         027    0001     88101   1               7    105
3 RD           I         01         027    0001     88101   1               7    105
4 RD           I         01         027    0001     88101   1               7    105
5 RD           I         01         027    0001     88101   1               7    105
6 RD           I         01         027    0001     88101   1               7    105
  Method     Date        Start.Time   Sample.Value Null.Data.Code
1   Year   Period Number of Samples Composite Type   Sample Value
2    120 19990103             00:00                            AS
3    120 19990106             00:00                            AS
4    120 19990109             00:00                            AS
5    120 19990112             00:00          8.841               
6    120 19990115             00:00          14.92               
        Sampling.Frequency Monitor.Protocol..MP..ID Qualifier...1 Qualifier...2
1 Monitor Protocol (MP) ID            Qualifier - 1 Qualifier - 2 Qualifier - 3
2                        3                                                     
3                        3                                                     
4                        3                                                     
5                        3                                                     
6                        3                                                     
  Qualifier...3 Qualifier...4 Qualifier...5 Qualifier...6 Qualifier...7
1 Qualifier - 4 Qualifier - 5 Qualifier - 6 Qualifier - 7 Qualifier - 8
2                                                                      
3                                                                      
4                                                                      
5                                                                      
6                                                                      
  Qualifier...8  Qualifier...9                    Qualifier...10
1 Qualifier - 9 Qualifier - 10 Alternate Method Detectable Limit
2                                                               
3                                                               
4                                                               
5                                                               
6                                                               
  Alternate.Method.Detectable.Limit Uncertainty year
1                       Uncertainty          NA 1999
2                                            NA 1999
3                                            NA 1999
4                                            NA 1999
5                                            NA 1999
6                                            NA 1999
>
```

DPUT:

```
> dput(pm_1999[1:20])
c(X..RD = "# RD,Action Code,State Code,County Code,Site ID,Parameter,POC,Sample Duration,Unit,Method,Date,Start Time,Sample Value,Null Data Code,Sampling Frequency,Monitor Protocol (MP) ID,Qualifier - 1,Qualifier - 2,Qualifier - 3,Qualifier - 4,Qualifier - 5,Qualifier - 6,Qualifier - 7,Qualifier - 8,Qualifier - 9,Qualifier - 10,Alternate Method Detectable Limit,Uncertainty", 
Action.Code = "# RC,Action Code,State Code,County Code,Site ID,Parameter,POC,Unit,Method,Year,Period,Number of Samples,Composite Type,Sample Value,Monitor Protocol (MP) ID,Qualifier - 1,Qualifier - 2,Qualifier - 3,Qualifier - 4,Qualifier - 5,Qualifier - 6,Qualifier - 7,Qualifier - 8,Qualifier - 9,Qualifier - 10,Alternate Method Detectable Limit,Uncertainty", 
State.Code = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990103,00:00,,AS,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
County.Code = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990106,00:00,,AS,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Site.ID = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990109,00:00,,AS,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Parameter = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990112,00:00,8.841,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
POC = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990115,00:00,14.92,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Sample.Duration = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990118,00:00,3.878,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Unit = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990121,00:00,9.042,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Method = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990124,00:00,5.464,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Date = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990127,00:00,20.17,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Start.Time = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990130,00:00,11.56,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Sample.Value = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990202,00:00,13.68,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Null.Data.Code = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990205,00:00,7.251,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Sampling.Frequency = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990208,00:00,11.47,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Monitor.Protocol..MP..ID = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990211,00:00,13.46,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Qualifier...1 = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990214,00:00,46.20,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Qualifier...2 = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990217,00:00,11.25,,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Qualifier...3 = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990220,00:00,,AN,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 
Qualifier...4 = "RD,I,01,027,0001,88101,1,7,105,120,19990223,00:00,,AN,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,"
)
>
```

A view of this resource from the R Studio environment, is below image.

[image: large single row data]

Comment: You can edit your question and add a sample of data using `dput(pm_1999[1:20])` and pasting the output in your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string on comma and `rbind` the list as rows. We can assign the headers from the first row and remove that row from the dataframe.

```
#Split the data on comma and create a list
df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(pm_1999, ','))
#Assign headers from 1st row of the data
names(df) <- df[1, ]
#Remove the 1st row from the data
df <- df[-1, ]
```